# NullPointExceptionError help needed

Tags: java, user-interface, error-handling, icons

I would like to apply icons to my program, but it gives me an error. It looks all good, that is why I dont have a clue what is wrong with it.

```
public static ImageIcon createIcon (String path) {
    URL url = System.class.getResource(path);

    if(url == null) {
        System.err.println("Unable to load image: " + path);
    }

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url); //here is line 30 in class Utils

    return icon;
}
```

And his is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at gui.Utils.createIcon(Utils.java:30)
```

Comment: Do you see the message logged "Unable to load Image..."? If not, instead of `System.err.println(...)` you can use `System.out.println(...)`... it seems that your `path` is null

Comment: No I dont see the message "Unable to load image"

Comment: Then use the `.out.` method instead... you will see it is null. So wrap your `new ImageIcon(...)` inside an if statement checking for not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `url` is `null`. Check how the constructor has been implemented:

```
public ImageIcon (URL location) {
    this(location, location.toExternalForm());
}
```

If `location` is `null`, `location.toExternalForm()` will throw `NullPointerException`.

In fact, if `path` is `null`, that too can cause `NullPointerException`. See how `getResource` has been implemented.

```
public URL getResource(String name) {
    name = resolveName(name);
    //...
}

private String resolveName(String name) {
    if (!name.startsWith("/")) {
        Class<?> c = this;
        while (c.isArray()) {
            c = c.getComponentType();
        }
        String baseName = c.getPackageName();
        if (baseName != null && !baseName.isEmpty()) {
            name = baseName.replace('.', '/') + "/" + name;
        }
    } else {
        name = name.substring(1);
    }
    return name;
}
```

As you can see, if `name` is `null`, `name.startsWith("/")` will throw `NullPointerException`.

Do it as follows:

```
public static ImageIcon createIcon (String path) {
    if(path == null) {
        System.err.println("Path is null");
        return null;
    }

    URL url = System.class.getResource(path);
    ImageIcon icon = null;

    if(url != null) {
        icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Unable to load image: " + path);
    }

    return icon;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesnt give me the error, but it also doesnt load the image. This is the line in another class where I call the image, but it gives me error, where I posted the code: treeCellRenderer.setLeafIcon(Utils.createIcon("/images/149407.webp"));

Comment: Debug/Print `path` and `url` to check their value.